# List: filter tweets from one list to another - Twitter API

Tags: list, twitterapi-python

I have a list containing many tweets called k1_tweets_filtered.

I have a function called pre_process which removes special characters, URLs etc from the stored tweets.

I want to create a new list which contains all tweets from k1_tweets_filtered after they have been processed by pre_process and call it k1_tweets_processed.

What code could I write to do the above? I tried the following but it produces a TypeError

```
k1_tweets_processed = []
for i in k1_tweets_filtered:
    pre_process(k1_tweets_filtered[i]['text'])
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Comment: In your code, the `i` is not the list index of the tweet dict. `i` is the tweet dict itself. So you probably want to rename `i` to something like `tweetDict` and say `tweetDict['text']` in the loop body.

Comment: It's also not a list comprehension you're working with. It's just a list. So you should probably remove that from this post's title and tag list.